# Associations in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, associations

I have 2 `db tables` : Users & Projects.

Fields of Users table are :
id, name, username, password, email, address, phone.

Fields of Projects table are :
id, name, description, user_id, deadline, budget.

What I need is that, I'll have 1 form, where there will be all fields from these 2 tables. And, when I submit the form, these fields will be saved in these 2 tables.

For example, my form will be like this :

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('User');
    echo $this->Form->input('name',array('type'=>'text','div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('username',array('type'=>'text','div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('password',array('type'=>'password','div'=>'false));
    echo $this->Form->input('email',array('type'=>'email','div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('address',array('type'=>'textarea','div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('phone',array('type'=>'tel','div'=>false));

    echo $this->Form->input('name',array('type'=>'text','div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('description',array('type'=>'text','div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('deadline',array('type'=>'date','div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('budget',array('type'=>'num','div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->submit('Save');
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Now, I want that when I submit the form, the fields will be saved in the corresponding tables; `Users` table will receive & save its fields, and `Projects` table will receive & save its fields.
For this, I tried `hasMany` association between `Users` & `Projects` tables, means, each user from `Users` table will have many projects from `Projects` table.

In `User.php`, I tried this :

```
class User extends AppModel{
   public $hasMany=array(
              'Project'=>array(
              'className'=>'Project')
   );
}
```

I thought it'd work, but it didn't, only `Users` table get its values, no value goes to `Project` table. What is the problem here ? What should I do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your view

```
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('name',array('type'=>'text','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('username',array('type'=>'text','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('password',array('type'=>'password','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('email',array('type'=>'email','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('address',array('type'=>'textarea','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('phone',array('type'=>'tel','div'=>false));

echo $this->Form->input('Project.0.name',array('type'=>'text','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('Project.0.description',array('type'=>'text','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('Project.0.deadline',array('type'=>'date','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('Project.0.budget',array('type'=>'num','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->submit('Save');
echo $this->Form->end();
```

And in your controller you have to use

```
$this->User->saveAssociated($data);
```

see the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array) about how to save associated data

Answer (score 1):

At first, add the model names `User` and `Project` as prefix to your form fields to separate them:

**View**:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('User.name',array('type'=>'text','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('User.username',array('type'=>'text','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('User.password',array('type'=>'password','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('User.email',array('type'=>'email','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('User.address',array('type'=>'textarea','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('User.phone',array('type'=>'tel','div'=>false));

echo $this->Form->input('Project.name',array('type'=>'text','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('Project.description',array('type'=>'text','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('Project.deadline',array('type'=>'date','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('Project.budget',array('type'=>'num','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->submit('Save');
echo $this->Form->end();
```

At second, use the separation to save your data into different models. Do not forget to add an associated column `user_id` to your table `projects`.

**Controller**

```
class UserController extends AppController
{
    function create()
    {
        $this->loadModel('Project');

        if($this->request->is('post', 'put'))
        {
            $this->User->getDataSource()->begin($this); // Starts transaction
            if($this->User->save($this->request->data['User']))
            {
                // Success, save project now
                $this->request->data['Project']['user_id'] = $this->User->getLastInsertId();

                if($this->Project->save($this->request->data['Project']))
                {
                    $this->User->getDataSource()->commit($this); // Commit
                    // success
                } else {
                    $this->User->getDataSource()->rollback($this); // Rollback
                }
            } else {
                $this->User->getDataSource()->rollback($this); // Rollback
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tested this code → works.

Comment: In this case, is better to use saveAll, because saveAll works with transaction, so if your Project save fail, you won't go have a incomplete data save, or do It manually.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear to me but what I see is you need to save data using associations.

But an association is a connection between two Active Record models. Associations are created to maintain Primary Key-Foreign Key information between instances of the two models.

You will need to save your USERS table data first and get the primary ID of last saved and use it as user_id for PROJECTS table and save PROJECT table information creating a PROJECT instance.

Comment: Yeah, you are right, I want to save data "Using Associations". I have PRIMARY_KEY and FOREIGN_KEY in both tables. I just wanted to save the form data once at a time. Yes, I can save the data table by table manually, but I was just looking for any short-cut way. I thought CakePHP provides this functionality, but I didn't find anything like that.

Comment: Associations are used in context of fetching data. Only to link models and fetch data avoiding complex open queries.

Answer (score 0):

### view:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('User');
    echo $this->Form->input('name',array('type'=>'text','div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('username',array('type'=>'text','div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('password',array('type'=>'password','div'=>'false));
    echo $this->Form->input('email',array('type'=>'email','div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('address',array('type'=>'textarea','div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('phone',array('type'=>'tel','div'=>false));


    // adding associate model name to every field..    
    echo $this->Form->input('Project.name',array('type'=>'text','div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('Project.description',array('type'=>'text','div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('Project.deadline',array('type'=>'date','div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->input('Project.budget',array('type'=>'num','div'=>false));
    echo $this->Form->submit('Save');
    echo $this->Form->end();
```

Note: You can disable all 'div' on form creation.. Look documentation for details...

### User model:

```
class User extends AppModel{
   public $hasMany=array('Project');
}
```

### UsersController:

```
public function add(){
    if($this->request->is('post')){
       $this->User->create();
       if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){// if you association is correct, all associated data will save automatically. 
         $this->Session->setFlash('saved');
         $this->redirect('where you wants to redirect');
       }else{
         $this->Session->setFlash('Something went wrong. Try again');
       }

    }

}
```

Comment: I exactly tried this first, but didn;t work. By the way, thanks for your help. @Fazal Rasel

Answer (score 0):

Easy way with saveAll

```
<!-- View -->
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User');
echo $this->Form->input('name',array('type'=>'text','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('username',array('type'=>'text','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('password',array('type'=>'password','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('email',array('type'=>'email','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('address',array('type'=>'textarea','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('phone',array('type'=>'tel','div'=>false));

echo $this->Form->input('Project.0.name',array('type'=>'text','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('Project.0.description',array('type'=>'text','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('Project.0.deadline',array('type'=>'date','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->input('Project.0.budget',array('type'=>'num','div'=>false));
echo $this->Form->submit('Save');
echo $this->Form->end();
?>

<!-- Controller -->
<?php
class UserController extends AppController
{
    function create()
    {
        if($this->request->is('post', 'put'))
        {
            if($this->User->saveAll($this->request->data))
            {
                // Success - set your flashMessage
            } else {
                // Error - set your flashMessage
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```